# Predicted values in R when regression has a factor

Tags: r, regression, predict

I have the following regression:

```
a <- lm(y ~ factor(x) + z + factor(x) * z, data = dataset)
```

I want to get predicted values for when x = 1, for varying levels of z. I have been struggling to do this with the `predict` package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630056/generating-predicted-values-for-levels-of-factor-variable

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. When having problems with code, show what you actually tried and describe where the "struggle" is happening.

Comment: The results object already includes fitted values for all observations.  Is it that you want predicted values for specific combinations?  Are you literally typing `x=1` or are you using the factor "value" e.g. x="red"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a <- lm(y ~ factor(x) + z + factor(x)*z, data=dataset)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1), z = c(1,2,3))
predict(a, df)
```

The idea above is to create a data frame with values of `X` and `Z` you want to test your model on.

Comment: @ShelbyGrossman if you are satisfied do you mind selecting it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted it, but it seems to not reflect that. How would I go about selecting it as an answer?

Comment: @ShelbyGrossman  "tick" sign below the upvote and downvote arrows/triangles.

Answer (score 0):

For future postings, it is good practice to *always* include sample data. See [here how to provide a minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including sample data.

That aside, here is a simple example based on some sample data I generate.

```
# Generate sample data
set.seed(2017);
x <- as.numeric(gl(2, 10, 20));
z <- 1:20;
y <- 4 * x + 0.5 * z + rnorm(20);

# Fit model
fit <- lm(y ~ as.factor(x) + z + as.factor(x) * z);
summary(fit);
#    
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(x) + z + as.factor(x) * z)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
#-1.9283 -0.4702 -0.1270  0.7932  1.6648
#
#Coefficients:
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)      4.13695    0.79828   5.182 9.08e-05 ***
#as.factor(x)2    5.72079    2.17955   2.625  0.01839 *
#z                0.47615    0.12865   3.701  0.00194 **
#as.factor(x)2:z -0.09588    0.18195  -0.527  0.60544
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 1.169 on 16 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9522,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9432
#F-statistic: 106.3 on 3 and 16 DF,  p-value: 8.896e-11

# Predict for x = 1, and y = 1:5
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 1, z = 1:5));
#1        2        3        4        5
#4.613097 5.089242 5.565388 6.041533 6.517679
```

Note that if you want to `predict` the response based on new values of your predictor variables, you need to supply a `newdata` `data.frame`. Otherwise, `predict` will predict the response based on your original data.